# Replacing values that are larger than a specific parameter

Tags: pandas

I have a column in a dataframe where I want to replace all values that are larger than some specific ceiling. There are some NaN in my series - it roughly looks like this:

```
A
0.1
0.2
0.3
NaN
0.5
```

I've tried list comprehension, writing

```
Max = 0.4
df['A'] = df['A'].dropna().apply(lambda x: [y if y <= Max else Max for y in x])
```

But this returns TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

What am I doing wrong, please

Comment: Use `df['A'].clip(upper=Max)`

Comment: That is super elegant - thank you!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do that with this code.

```
Max = 0.4
df['A'] = df['A'].dropna().applymap(lambda x: max(x, Max))
```

Comment: Thank you very much - that is a really neat way of doing it!